# zsh using prezto startup prompt extremely slow

Tags: performance, zsh, zshrc, prezto

I'm using zsh with prezto. The startup prompt is extremely slow. I use iTerm2 on Mac.

[image]

Here is my `~/.zshrc`

```
#
# Executes commands at the start of an interactive session.
#
# Authors:
#   Sorin Ionescu <sorin.ionescu@gmail.com>
#

# Source Prezto.
if [[ -s "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zprezto/init.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zprezto/init.zsh"
fi


# Customize to your needs.
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
export PATH

# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

autoload -U +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit
```

Here is my `~/.zpreztorc`

```
zstyle ':prezto:load' pmodule \
  'environment' \
  'terminal' \
  'editor' \
  'history' \
  'directory' \
  'spectrum' \
  'utility' \
  'ssh' \
  'completion' \
  'homebrew' \
  'node' \
  'osx' \
  'git' \
  'syntax-highlighting' \
  'history-substring-search' \
  'autosuggestions' \
  'prompt'
```

I have a hunch that the order of the modules would make a difference ? Furthermore, I have also tried removing some modules but that didn't seem to make a difference either.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: No, I just got rid of my mac and went back to linux :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and the way I fixed the problem was:

Add this line to the very top of my `.zshrc` file:

```
zmodload zsh/zprof
```

That includes zsh profiling module, `zprof`, at the beginning of the file.

Then opened a new terminal session (so the changes would take place and `zprof` was loaded) and executed

```
zprof
```

It gave me a report of where did my system spent most of its time.

In my particular case it was executing `nvm`-related tasks. I suspect the OP had a similar issue, since they were loading the `node` module.

Since I rarely use node these days I just uninstalled everything Node-related, including nvm, and I also removed all the node and nvm related lines I had on my `.zshrc`.

This did it for me, so I commented out the `zmodload zsh/zprof` line from `.zshrc`.

While googling for this people who actually need to use Node on a daily basis have come up with other solutions.

For example here: https://xcv58.me/if-your-zsh-starts-very-slow-cb1434ea16bd

This person created a zprezto module called `zsh-lazy-load` ([repo](https://github.com/xcv58/zsh-lazy-load)) which can be used to [defer loading nvm until it's needed](https://github.com/xcv58/prezto-1/pull/2/files).

Disclaimer: I have not tried `zsh-lazy-load` myself so I cannot fully recommend it; just added it in case it was useful for anyone.